# why I cannot run COMMAND in add_custom_target

Tags: cmake

The following script makes me crazy:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

set(ProjectName ABC)
project(${ProjectName})


add_executable(EXE exe.c)


add_custom_target(Experiment
    COMMAND echo "hello"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENTS "run a test"
    )
add_dependencies(Experiment EXE)
set_target_properties(Experiment PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL false)
```

When I run the above scripts in Widnows for VC 2010, it can create a project. Within this project, there is a `Experiment` target. But, every time I run it, I have the following error message:

```
Error   1   error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151 6
```

I have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: Try to remove `COMMAND` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a misprint - `COMMENTS`, should be `COMMENT`. Otherwise I think CMake treat it as a part of `WORKING_DIRECTORY`. Also I recommend you to use `-E echo hello` command instead of `echo hello`. This will no make any difference in this particular case but it's a good habit to think in cross-platformic fashion always. Also the note about `COMMAND` is right, there is no need to use this keyword if it's only one command.

Summarize:

```
add_custom_target(
    Experiment
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "hello"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "run a test"
)
```